# If $\limsup(b_{n})=+\infty$, is $\limsup_{n}(b_{n} S_{n})=+\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, limsup-and-liminf

If $\limsup(b_{n})=+\infty$, $b_{n}$ and $S_{n}$ are nonnegative sequences. Is $\limsup_{n}(b_{n} S_{n})=+\infty$?

Comment: You may want to clarify your question as well as provide your efforts on it. Also please consider typesetting your question using $\LaTeX$. (See [*here*](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the basic.)

Comment: All you know about $S_n$ is that it's a nonnegative sequence?  How on earth do you expect to conclude anything about $\liminf_n (b_n S_n)$?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry.  I have a typo.  I am asking about lim sup(bnSn) not lim inf(bnSn).

Comment: I don't know how to edit my question.  Is there a way to edit the question?

Comment: @T.C. You can [edit] your question by clicking on the word (edit) just below your post.

Comment: Great.  Thanks for your help, Martin.  I am new at this.

Comment: I have to believe there was no effort on the part of the OP. This is the most generous interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: what if $b_n=n$ and $S_n=1/n$?

Answer (score 1):

Or simply $S_{n}=0$, then $\limsup_{n}(b_{n}S_{n})=0$.